In Node.js, do asynchronous file read/writes execute synchronously once started?
An async function in Node will only start executing in a future event loop. But once it starts, it will finish completely before the loop continues. The only exception, of course, being if that function itself contains other async functions. For example, in
async function foo() {
    x = 1;
    console.log(x);
}

This function won't run as soon as it's called, but once called it's guaranteed to never be interrupted. It will always log 1, even if there are other functions queued up at the same time that want to change x. But if were
async function foo() {
    x = 1;
    await someUnrelatedAsyncFunction();
    console.log(x);
}

now it's possible for it to log something other than 1, since even if someUnrelatedAsyncFunction doesn't itself touch x, some other function could have in the mean time.
My question is, do any of the basic functions in the fs module have internal asynchronicity in the process of reading/writing the file?
For example, if I run this snippet:
fs.appendFile("test.txt", "foo", a=>a);
fs.appendFile("test.txt", "bar", a=>a);

will the file always end up containing foobar? Can the writes get reversed, such that the result is barfoo? Can the writes get interleaved, such that it ends up with something like fboaor?
In general, what is the internal structure of functions like readFile, writeFile, unlink, etc.? Do they ever pass control back to the Javascript event loop in the middle of execution?

the docs say it's not guaranteed https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#notes

@YuriG. Ah, thank you. So that shows that they could be reversed, but what about interleaved? Will one function always start and end before another one can start?
